# Translating date into spanish Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I have the followwing site on Wordpress where you can find different schedules with the month in english and i need to change it to spanish:

http://comproautosusados.com/centrolerner2016/horarios/

I tried Loco Translate, trying editing the .pó files and now i'm looking into the theme's php files. I've been able to translate lots of stuff, but i can't translate the months. You can see at the left side of the table that it says "Lunes 28th April" for example. I need to change it to "Lunes 28 Abril".

In the theme's "core"there's this file: timetable.php where this function is found:

```
public function getDays() {
if (!isset(self::$cache['days'])) {
$days = array();
foreach ($this->get('calendar.period') as $time) {
$object = new VTCore_Wordpress_Objects_Array(array(
'id' => strtolower($time->format('l')),
'timestamp' => $time->getTimeStamp(),
'formatted' => $time->format($this->get('calendar.format')),
'iso' => $time->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO'),
'label' => $this->get('days.' . strtolower($time->format('l'))),
));
$days[] = $object;
}
self::$cache['days'] = $days;
}
return self::$cache['days'];
}
```

There is where the theme generates the date? i don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the same problem, maybe something like this will help you:

```
<?php

// Get the numeric representation of the current month
$m = date('n');

// Get a full textual representation of the month ( in norwegian )
if ($m==1)  { $t = "Januar"; }
if ($m==2)  { $t = "Februar"; }
if ($m==3)  { $t = "Mars"; }
if ($m==4)  { $t = "April"; }
if ($m==5)  { $t = "Mai"; }
if ($m==6)  { $t = "Juni"; }
if ($m==7)  { $t = "Juli"; }
if ($m==8)  { $t = "August"; }
if ($m==9)  { $t = "September"; }
if ($m==10) { $t = "Oktober"; }
if ($m==11) { $t = "November"; }
if ($m==12) { $t = "Desember"; }

// Display the date
echo date('m').".".$t.".".date('Y'); // returns: 05.Mai.2016

?>
```

Comment: Where do put that on my Wordpress? what file?

Comment: Yes, this actually helped. Thanks!